# Map on Scalaz Validation failure

Tags: scala, scalaz

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

"abc".parseInt
```

This will return a `Validation[NumberFormatException, Int]`.
Is there a way I can apply a function on the failure side (such as `toString`) to get a `Validation[String, Int]`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a pair of methods `<-:` and `:->` defined on `MAB[M[_,_], A, B]` that map on the left and right side of any `M[A, B]` as long as there is a `Bifunctor[M]`. `Validation` happens to be a bifunctor, so you can do this:

```
((_:NumberFormatException).toString) <-: "123".parseInt
```

Scala's type inference generally flows from left to right, so this is actually shorter:

```
"123".parseInt.<-:(_.toString)
```

And requires less annotation.

Comment: Nice. I wonder wether the following could be useful in MAB:  def bimap[C,D](first: A => C = identity[A] \_,  second: B => D = identity[B] \_)(implicit b: Bifunctor[M]): M[C, D] = b.bimap(value, first, second). So we get "123".parseInt.bimap(\_.toString)

Comment: That would be awesome. Send a pull request.

Answer (score 11):

There is a functor on FailProjection. So you could do

```
v.fail.map(f).validation
```

(fail to type as FailProjection, validation to get out of it)

Alternatively

```
v.fold(f(_).failure, _.success)
```

Both a bit verbose. Maybe someone more familiar with scalaz can come up with something better

Comment: can't get the `f andthen Failure` to work: `"123".parseInt.fold(_.toString andThen Failure)` prints `type mismatch`. The other one works fine.

Comment: @huynhjl: fold takes two functions: the first for the error case, the seconde for the success case. v.fold(_.toString.fail, _.success) works

Comment: But fold arguments have default values (identities) have they not ?

Comment: @Apocalisp. Thanks.Now I have to find where failure is defined :-)

Comment: foldArguments have default values: Ok, not the proper ones here, identity is not what we want

Comment: _.failure and _.success are defined on Identity, like most other things that apply to types of kind `*`.