# How to map on failure of ValidationNel?

Tags: validation, scalaz

I've [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516613/map-on-scalaz-validation-failure) that `Validation` has methods `:->` and `<-:` to map on the success and failure.

```
scala> val failure: Validation[String, Unit] = "xxx".failure
failure: scalaz.Validation[String,Unit] = Failure(xxx)

scala> failure.<-:("!!!" + _)
res17: scalaz.Validation[String,Unit] = Failure(!!!xxx)
```

Unfortunately `<-:` does not exist for `ValidationNel`:

```
scala> val failure: ValidationNel[String, Unit] = "xxx".failureNel
failure: scalaz.ValidationNel[String,Unit] = Failure(NonEmptyList(xxx))

scala> failure.<-:(nel => nel + "!!!")
<console>:15: error: value <-: is not a member of scalaz.ValidationNel[String,Unit]
          failure.<-:(nel => nel + "!!!")
```

Interesting that it does compile if I define may `failure` as `Validation[NonEmptyList[String], Unit]`.

Now I wonder if there is another way to use `<-:` for `ValidationNel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, you won't be able to conjure a Bifunctor instance for ValidationNel, but ValidationNel is really just a type alias for Validation[NonEmptyList[?], ?], and that does, as you know, have a Bifunctor instance. If you coerce the type of your value from ValidationNel to just Validation, things will start to work:

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> val failure: Validation[String, Unit] = "xxx".failure
failure: scalaz.Validation[String,Unit] = Failure(xxx)

scala> failure.<-:("!!!" + _)
res0: scalaz.Validation[String,Unit] = Failure(!!!xxx)

scala> val failure: ValidationNel[String, Unit] = "xxx".failureNel
failure: scalaz.ValidationNel[String,Unit] = Failure(NonEmptyList(xxx))

scala> failure.<-:("!!!" <:: _)
<console>:15: error: value <-: is not a member of scalaz.ValidationNel[String,Unit]
              failure.<-:("!!!" <:: _)
                      ^

scala> val failure2: Validation[NonEmptyList[String], Unit] = failure
failure2: scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[String],Unit] = Failure(NonEmptyList(xxx))

scala> failure2.<-:("!!!" <:: _)
res2: scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[String],Unit] = Failure(NonEmptyList(!!!, xxx))
```

however, you can also just call the leftMap method on Validation:

```
scala> failure2.leftMap("!!!" <:: _)
res3: scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[String],Unit] =      Failure(NonEmptyList(!!!, xxx))

scala> failure.leftMap("!!!" <:: _)
res4: scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[String],Unit] = Failure(NonEmptyList(!!!, xxx))
```

or use "swapped" to swap failure and success, rightMap the swapped value, then swap them back:

```
scala> failure.swapped(_ :-> ("!!!" <:: _))
res5: scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[String],Unit] = Failure(NonEmptyList(!!!, xxx))
```